# не работает код на Си

Tags: c

нужна помощь с кодом, задача такова "найти все трехзначные числа, которые можно представить разностью между квадратом числа, образованного первыми двумя цифрами и квадратом третьей цифры." В этом коде выскакивает ошибка

```
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++);
if (i == (pow(int(i / 10),2) - pow((i % 10),2)));
printf("\n Vvedite znachenye i=");
return 0;
getch();
}
```

Comment: ошибка такая: [Error] name lookup of "i" changed for ISO "for" scoping [-fpermessive]  и [Note] (if you use "-fpermessive" G++ will accept your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() {for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++);
```

Точка с запятой завершила ваш цикл... `i` больше не видна.

```
if (i == (pow(int(i / 10),2) - pow((i % 10),2)));
```

Опять же - если условие верно - вы **ничего не делаете** - пустая инструкция `;`...

```
printf("\n Vvedite znachenye i=");
```

Зачем что-то вводить?

```
return 0;
```

Все, выход из функции, так что код

```
getch();
}
```

никогда выполнен не будет.

Тогда уж [так](https://ideone.com/qcLhM2):

```
int main() 
{
    for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (i == (i/10)*(i/10) - (i%10)*(i%10))
            printf("i =  %d\n",i);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну вот Вы совсем не хотите чтоб человек сам подумал)

Comment: @Arenoros Посмотрите его первый вопрос - там он вообще ничего не написал... Считай, прогресс. А после того, как он начал вас спрашивать по каждой строчке, я понял, что толку от педагогики будет мало...

Comment: Видел) но я пытаюсь понять глубину пропасти, если человек просто не хочет думать то и помогать я смысла не вижу

Answer (score 1):

Вы поставили `;` после

```
for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++);
```

на этом область видимости `i` закончена

Comment: убрал ";" код начал компелироватся но на консоли написано только "Vvedite znachenye i=" а ввести цифру туда я не могу, как толкьо нажимаю на клавишу консоль проподает

Comment: @Ramazan, я конечно извиняюсь, но вы свой код сами видите? В какой момент по вашему вы вводите значение?(напишите строчку кода в комментарии)

Comment: извиняюсь я в этом деле не так давно и не очень хорошо разбираюсь, я думал что в строчке printf("\n Vvedite znachenye  i=") я должен на консоли ввести значения 100 и 1000,не правильно понял то что прочитал в интернете

Comment: @Ramazan, Вы изучаете язык сами для себя или вам его так преподают где то? Может лучше посоветовать материал для изучения чем вот так кусочно закрывать ошибки?

Comment: преподают в универе, да посоветуйте пожалуйста, было бы хорошо

Comment: @Ramazan, это наверное лучшая серия курсов по С++ для начинающих https://www.coursera.org/learn/c-plus-plus-white

Если интересно, вот доклад одного из авторов этого курса https://youtu.be/mhiAXYprh34

Единственное что я бы поменял это IDE на VisualStudio 2019 если у вас учат под windows, но если с этим возникают сложности лучше следовать курсу.

Comment: @Ramazan, если что курс и его задания можно выполнять бесплатно, для этого при записи на курс чуть ниже есть ссылка **Прослушать курс**. Разница лишь в том что после вам не дадут сертификат.

Comment: хорошо спасибоо, а есть курсы по Си?, так же есть вопрос какой компилятор лучше скачать на данный момент у меня стоит Dev-C++, долго думаю скачать Visual Studio но сомневаюсь как то

Comment: @Ramazan грубо говоря Си это подмножество С++, всё есть в том же курсе. OMG.. смело ставь VS

Comment: Все хорошо, уже скачиваю ;)